# Segmentation fault when using qsort and printf

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, printf, qsort

I'm trying to make a program to crack passwords by searching through a file of md5 hashes and using bsearch to find them in a rockyou database. My problem is that I'm running into a segmentation fault that is either caused by my qsort or my printf (I've run Valgrind and it says printf, but manipulating qsort changes the error output). I can't seem to find the solution online, though I've tried flushing stdout and different ways to size the array in the qsort function.

`char **dict = read_dict( argv[2] );`

read_dict, which I haven't placed here because it's a hefty chunk of code, takes in the dictionary file, splits it into an array of strings, formats it into hash:password, and mallocs the space for it. It then returns the pointer of the array of pointers that contains each string.

```
int qcompare( const void *a, const void *b)
  {
  return strncmp( *((char **)a), *((char **)b), HASH_LEN);
  }
```

`qsort(dict, (sizeof(dict) / sizeof(dict[0])), sizeof(char *), qcompare);`

```
for (int i = 0; dict[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
    printf("%s\n", dict[i]);
    }
```

The printf shown here isn't the actual one I'm using, it's just a simpler one I was trying to use to debug my code. It's my first time posting so hopefully I haven't done anything atrociously wrong with formatting this question. Thank you in advance for any help I get.

read_dict as requested

```
 char **read_dict(char *filename)
 {
 FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
 if (!f)
    {
    printf("read_dict: file error message\n");
    exit(1);
    }

int arrlen = 0;
int i =  0;
char **dict = NULL;
char buf[PASS_LEN];
while (fgets(buf, PASS_LEN, f) != NULL)
    {
    if (i == arrlen)
        {
        arrlen += STEPSIZE;
        char **newdict = realloc(dict, arrlen * sizeof(char*));
        if (!newdict)
            {
            printf("read_dict: newdict error message\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        dict = newdict;
        }// end of if

    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    int slen = strlen(buf);
    char *pass = malloc( (slen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(pass, buf);

    char output[(HASH_LEN + PASS_LEN + 1)];
    sprintf(output, "%s:%s", md5(pass, strlen(pass)), pass );

    dict[i] = output;
    i++;
    }// end of while

if (i == arrlen)
    {
    char **newarr = realloc(dict, (arrlen + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    if (!newarr)
        {
        printf("read_dict: newarr error message\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    dict = newarr;
    }

dict[i] = NULL;
return dict;
}// end of read_dict
```

Comment: `sizeof(dict) / sizeof(dict[0])` is not the right array size.  `sizeof(dict)` is the size of a pointer.  I also suspect you have a problem in  unposted "takes in the dictionary file, splits it into an array of strings, formats it into hash:password, and mallocs the space for it.".  Best to post code than describe it.  Add enough code so we may replicate the problem.

Comment: I've added my read_dict program like you asked. I had also already tried using just sizeof(dict) without dividing it, but that threw a segmentation fault as well.

Comment: Any kind of `sizeof` application for the purposes of determining the array size would make no sense whatsoever . Stop trying to use `sizeof` for this.

Comment: I'm asking for help, not for criticism. If you would suggest something different that would be helpful for me.

Comment: A couple comments which probably don't have must to do with your problem: please use `strdup()` instead of `strlen();malloc();strcpy();` sequences and `char output[(HASH_LEN + PASS_LEN + 1)]; sprintf(output, "%s:%s", md5(pass, strlen(pass)), pass );` might not have enough space on the `output` buffer. Remember that the buffer needs space fot he ':' and a null terminator in addition to the copies of the strings.

Comment: More to the point of your problem: `read_dict()` keeps track of how many items have been added to the array pointed to by `dict`, you need to  get that information out of `read_dict()`. Either pass in a pointer to a `size_t` variable that `read_dict()` can write the count into or put a null ptr after the last valid item so that whatever needs to know how many valid elements are there can simply scan the array for to count the number of valid elements before the null pointer sentinel at the end. The same idea that allows anything to figure out how many characters are in a string.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I tried making a size variable that `read_dict()` incremented when it made a new string, but when I put that in as the size in `qsort`, I still got a segmentation fault from Valgrind. As for the null ptr, isn't that what I have at the very bottom of the code with `dict[i]= NULL`? I'm still a student so I'm just making sure, I never know what I'm ignorant about.

Comment: Yes, the `dict[i] = NULL` will put a null pointer that can be used as a sentinel so anything can count how many elements are in the array.  I just noticed that the pointers being put into the array are the address of the local variable `output`. That's a huge problem; try `dict[i] = strdup(output);` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Seems like that was it! Valgrind brought back no errors and the printf worked just fine. Thank you so much! I'm still relatively new with pointers so I'll be sure to pay closer attention to what I'm really assigning things to.