# Why are the values getting overwritten in the char pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Below is the snippet of a function store(). Here the attempt is to store the address of char arrays in a char pointer array (char *subsequence[] --> which stores all the address of all strings). Here the strings are stored in the char array called dest, whose address is to be stored in subsequence[].

When assigning the values (subsequence[subsequence_index++]=dest), it overwrites the previous values.

Code:

```
subsequence_size=0;   /** global variable*/
subsequence_index=0;  /** global variable*/

void store(int length, char dest[]) {
int index;

if(length > subsequence_size) { 
printf("Will enter the nullifying loop\n");
    for(index=0; index<MAXLEN; index++)
        subsequence[index]=NULL;
    subsequence_size++;
    subsequence_index=0;
}

printf("Assigning value to store....index=%d\n",subsequence_index);
subsequence[subsequence_index++]=dest;

printf("Printing subsequence\n");
for(index=0; index<subsequence_index; index++)
    printf("%s, ",subsequence[index]);
printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

Will enter the nullifying loop

Assigning value to store....index=0

Printing subsequence

a,

Assigning value to store....index=1

Printing subsequence

n, n,

Assigning value to store....index=2

Printing subsequence

t, t, t,

Here the store had initially 'a' but later when appended with 'n' it overwrote the previous value at index 0(i.e 'a'). Same thing is repeated when dest is passed to the function with a value 't'.

Thanks.

Comment: Show how `store` is called.  Even better, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I predict `dest` is a buffer that is reused for new content.  So the same pointer is being placed in the array repeatedly and the buffer that pointer refers to is updated with new content.

Comment: See the last couple of comments in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43579318/12711

Comment: The values aren't getting overwritten in the char pointer array. You have an array that contains the same pointer a bunch of times (each entry points to the same variable) and you are overwriting that variable.

Comment: Hi @aschepler this is how the store is called each time --> store(length,dest); from another function via a loop where dest is a char array. 

Yes Michael dest gets itself a new value in each iteration of the loop and a call is made to store.

Comment: No, edit your question to paste the entire function that calls `store`.

Comment: Hi @immibis, yes that was the actual issue. The address was having the new values everytime, so when printing, it was displaying the changed values at that same address.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs in helping me out with this. Appreciated. :)